# Can Anaconda tell you Conda-Forge url of an installed package?

Tags: python, installation, package, anaconda, conda

I'm trying to build a dependency tree for a series of python package installs, and I'd like to include the conda-forge url for each package.

Is there a way to find the url of an installed package using the command line interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not specific to *Conda Forge*, but yes, the `--explicit` flag does this.

### Example

```bash
$ conda list -n foo
# packages in environment at /Users/mfansler/mambaforge-arm64/envs/foo:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
bzip2                     1.0.8                h3422bc3_4    conda-forge
ca-certificates           2022.12.7            h4653dfc_0    conda-forge
libffi                    3.4.2                h3422bc3_5    conda-forge
libsqlite                 3.40.0               h76d750c_0    conda-forge
libzlib                   1.2.13               h03a7124_4    conda-forge
ncurses                   6.3                  h07bb92c_1    conda-forge
openssl                   3.0.7                h03a7124_1    conda-forge
pip                       22.3.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
python                    3.11.0          h3ba56d0_1_cpython    conda-forge
readline                  8.1.2                h46ed386_0    conda-forge
setuptools                66.0.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
tk                        8.6.12               he1e0b03_0    conda-forge
tzdata                    2022g                h191b570_0    conda-forge
wheel                     0.38.4             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
xz                        5.2.6                h57fd34a_0    conda-forge

$ conda list --explicit -n foo
# This file may be used to create an environment using:
# $ conda create --name <env> --file <this file>
# platform: osx-arm64
@EXPLICIT
https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-arm64/bzip2-1.0.8-h3422bc3_4.tar.bz2
https://conda.anaconda.org/t/me-c2e2628a-32b1-44fd-94f7-2dffce561198/conda-forge/osx-arm64/ca-certificates-2022.12.7-h4653dfc_0.conda
https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-arm64/libffi-3.4.2-h3422bc3_5.tar.bz2
https://conda.anaconda.org/t/me-c2e2628a-32b1-44fd-94f7-2dffce561198/conda-forge/osx-arm64/libzlib-1.2.13-h03a7124_4.tar.bz2
https://conda.anaconda.org/t/me-c2e2628a-32b1-44fd-94f7-2dffce561198/conda-forge/osx-arm64/ncurses-6.3-h07bb92c_1.tar.bz2
https://conda.anaconda.org/t/me-c2e2628a-32b1-44fd-94f7-2dffce561198/conda-forge/noarch/tzdata-2022g-h191b570_0.conda
https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-arm64/xz-5.2.6-h57fd34a_0.tar.bz2
https://conda.anaconda.org/t/me-c2e2628a-32b1-44fd-94f7-2dffce561198/conda-forge/osx-arm64/libsqlite-3.40.0-h76d750c_0.tar.bz2
https://conda.anaconda.org/t/me-c2e2628a-32b1-44fd-94f7-2dffce561198/conda-forge/osx-arm64/openssl-3.0.7-h03a7124_1.conda
https://conda.anaconda.org/t/me-c2e2628a-32b1-44fd-94f7-2dffce561198/conda-forge/osx-arm64/readline-8.1.2-h46ed386_0.tar.bz2
https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-arm64/tk-8.6.12-he1e0b03_0.tar.bz2
https://conda.anaconda.org/t/me-c2e2628a-32b1-44fd-94f7-2dffce561198/conda-forge/osx-arm64/python-3.11.0-h3ba56d0_1_cpython.conda
https://conda.anaconda.org/t/me-c2e2628a-32b1-44fd-94f7-2dffce561198/conda-forge/noarch/setuptools-66.0.0-pyhd8ed1ab_0.conda
https://conda.anaconda.org/t/me-c2e2628a-32b1-44fd-94f7-2dffce561198/conda-forge/noarch/wheel-0.38.4-pyhd8ed1ab_0.tar.bz2
https://conda.anaconda.org/t/me-c2e2628a-32b1-44fd-94f7-2dffce561198/conda-forge/noarch/pip-22.3.1-pyhd8ed1ab_0.tar.bz2
```